# Unable to sign in to Xcode

Tags: xcode

My Xcode was working fine until an hour back. Now, it has started acting up. I automatically got logged out of my developer account, of which I am a member. Now, whenever I try to login I am thrown this error.

Your session has expired.  Please log in.
Try signing in again or contact Apple Developer Support to resolve account access issues.

I have tried looking into the forums but to no avail. 
[Apple Forums.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23674)

I am unable to make builds because of this. Every time I try to login, it shows up this error.

Does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Contact Apple Developer Support

Comment: have you checked by logging Apple developer ? by Means Membership is not expired.

Comment: The member ship seems to be just fine. I have successfully logged into the developer portal. 
I have contacted Apple Developer Support as well. But I do not expect a reply anytime soon.

Comment: @jarora some times xcode lags. With Xcode8 it happens everytime. try to quit Xcode and restart mac.

Comment: Tried every possible thing. Restarting my life is the only strategy left.

Comment: @jarora maybe the clock of your Mac isn't adjusted correctly? Did you try to reinstall Xcode? Or at least try to login from Xcode in another Mac... It can help you narrow down the issue

Comment: I tried logging into someone else's laptop, but to no avail. Still getting the same issue. The interesting part is that all my other teammates' developer accounts are working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the options worked for me, so I contacted Apple developer support. They confirmed that there was an issue at their end and now it's resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just faced same problem and solution was:

You need to enable Two-factor authentication for Apple ID

[Read here how to do this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915)

Comment: I already have Two-factor auth ON. The problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened for me as well. Turning on two factor authentication resolved this issue. 
If you have already enabled it, turn it off and then turn it on again and see.

Comment: I just had a similar issue, and turning it off and back on again worked for me! Interestingly they directed me through an entirely different process for turning it on than I had gone through the first time.